# How do you hide generated .js files VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following settings.json

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).tsx" }
    }
}
```

I would like to exclude generated .js files produced by .ts and .tsx files. Is there a syntax to specify both .ts and .tsx in the when?

Comment: Don't know if that would work, but have you tried using a wildcard? `"when":"$(basename).ts?"`

Comment: It's kind of hacky, but it works, defining another expression that matches the same files.